# HTML video buffering freeze

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm making custom video controls, I have a `@progress` event which is used to track how much the video has buffered and update the width of a progress bar `div`:

```
<video @progress="videoBuffer($event)">
```

```
videoBuffer(e) {
  if (e.target.buffered.length === 1)
    // videoBuffered passed as props to the controls
    this.videoBuffered = (e.target.buffered.end(0) / e.target.duration) * 100;
},
```

```
<div
  class="dk__video-buffered"
  :style="{ maxWidth: videoBuffered + '%' }"
></div>
```

This works fine if you play the video from start to finish and don't click past the buffered range:

[image: Video progress bar working]

This also works when scrubbing with the thumb.

However, if you click past the buffered range, it freezes:

[image: Video progress bar freezing]

Code for the click event:

```
<div
  class="dk__video-track-container"
  @click="trackTime($event)"
>
  <div class="dk__video-track">
    <div
      class="dk__video-played"
      :style="{ width: playedWidth + '%' }"
    ></div>
    <div
      class="dk__video-buffered"
      :style="{ maxWidth: videoBuffered + '%' }"
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
trackTime(e) {
  // Set the videos time on click
  this.video.currentTime =
    (e.offsetX / e.target.offsetParent.offsetWidth) * this.videoDuration;
},
```

At first I thought this would be an issue with Vue's reactivity as I'm passing the buffer data through props, but, when I `console.log(e.target.buffered.end(0))` I can see that the data itself freezes on whatever position it was at when clicked.

Does anyone have any idea why this is or how I can work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `end(0)` which will return the end of the **first** [time range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges).

Since you have skipped a part of the video, you have multiple time range's [buffered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/buffered), but you will continue displaying the first (index 0) section.

To jump forwards, you could use `e.target.buffered.end(e.target.buffered.length - 1)`, however since time range's are ordered, this will not always work for jumping backwards. You may need to iterate through the time-range's and find the one which contains your current position in the media.

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't fix it unfortunately. If I `console.log(e.target.buffered.end(e.target.length - 1));` and click past, the number still freezes. You're right that the index changes though, if I `console.log(e.target.buffered);`, I can see the `length` increasing to 2 and then 3, just not sure what to do with this information

Comment: I mistyped it! Just changed it to `e.target.buffered.end(e.target.buffered.length - 1)` and it worked! Thanks @DBS

Comment: It's worth noting, Firefox is still temperamental. All other browsers are working fine.